# Abstract out render method to add to it with custom components

Tags: reactjs

I have an interesting problem. I have a component. I need to allow the user to override the existing render method with one of their own. Each custom render may act differently. Currently, I'm trying to keep the existing code in place, while abstracting out the custom code. Example:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class ShowThis extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <> </>
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      open: false
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

        // this is the custom component
        // this is highly coupled and needs to be moved out of App
        // but I need to allow other custom components like ShowThis to handle the rendering also
        {this.state.open && <ShowThis />} 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I've seen render props but I'm not sure how to go about it. Looking for help to solve this problem.
Looking for something like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class ShowThis extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TheMainCodeFromApp />
      <p>my custom code also </p>
    )
  }
}

class ShowThat extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <p>my custom code also </p>
      <TheMainCodeFromApp />
      <p>my custom code also </p>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      open: false
    }
  }

  if (this.props.module) {
    module.render()
  } else {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: what is `<TheMainCodeFromApp />` supposed to be?

Comment: the else render with the header tags with hello codesandbox and start editing, that stuff

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're pretty much there. Here's an example of a very basic render prop pattern.

```
const RenderContainer = ({render}) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return <div onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>
    {open && render()}
  </div>;
};

// Used like
const Comp1 = () => {
  return <RenderContainer render={() => <ShowThis />} />;
};
```

Comment: I think I'm having a hard time understanding the specifics of how this is supposed to work in my case. I need the code in `App` to change as little as possible. I don't want to move that code into a different component. I just want to add on to it in a modular way.

Comment: I don't follow at all. You'll have to rephrase your question and desired outcome.